Express js swagger dynamic routes
I have an express application, that I am reading some JSON files and creating the application routes based on those JSON files. Each object of the JSON files, describes the request type, the path, the controller and the method of that controller. Is there a way to document these routes with OpenAPI? If no is there another way that maybe can help? Thanks in advance.
Example of route inside JSON:
{
    path: 'api/whatever',
    type: 'post',
    controller: 'whatever',
    method: 'whatever'
}

I want a solution like jdoc if possible, but I don't know if is possible to add dynamic parameters.

you might try typespec.io .. it's a language on top of OpenAPI which allows you to write more concise definitions similar to your question

@JeremyFiel My classes are typeOrm classes. I want if possible to implement a solution there. Typespec if I understand correctly is about creating new classes and definitions, I don't want to write my classes again. Is there a solution to implement this inside my .ts classes?

not sure, it was just a suggestion I've seen out in the wild.
